# GLKView snapshot returning an empty image only on ipad 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ipad-3, glkview

I have a `GLKView` that have a camera stream displaying. When I try to take a snapshot of that view in ipad 3 by making

```
[_glkView snapshot];
```

the `UIImage` generated have the correct size but the content is empty. However, if I run the same code on `iPad` Air it works perfectly.

Any ideas? Thanks.